# Django Celery autoretry_for and retry_policy

Tags: python, django, celery

we're using django 1.10, celery 4.1.0

I noticed that when sending 'autoretry_for' parameter as job setting and 'retry_policy' to apply_async(), the retry policy is totally ignored. instead, it uses the 'default_retry_delay' and the default max retry, which is 3.

for example:
job settings:

```
'default': {
    'soft_time_limit': 10,
    'default_retry_delay': 10,
    'autoretry_for': ('billiard.exceptions.SoftTimeLimitExceeded',
                      'app.utils.exceptions.FlowInternalServerErrorException',),
    'on_retry': 'app.tasks.common_tasks.on_task_retry',
    'celery_countdown': 0,
    'expires': 86400,
    'retry': True,
    'retry_policy': {
        'max_retries': 1,
        'interval_start': 0,
        'interval_step': 0.2,
        'interval_max': 0.2,
    },
```

when the task is executed and it receives the  'FlowInternalServerErrorException' as in the 'autoretry_for', it will ignore the 'retry_policy' setting and will use 3 max retries and 10 seconds between retries.

Is there a way to use the 'retry_policy' when facing one of the 'autoretry_for' exceptions?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to go, but after taking a look at how autoretry_for is implemented in Celery, it only takes the parameters that are registered on the task/shared_task decorator on the task definition. therefore imo you can either override the base celery task class and add a bit more logic in the on_retry function (just add the retry_policy args to the super.on_retry call args), or just use the basic retry functionality (not sure if these are the best options, but they work :) )